# javascript in html not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html page linked to jquery page but can't get it to work. I am using the jquery to look for cells where the cell value is below 3000 which should then fill the cell, bit it doesn't work at present.

Here is the html code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    rr();
})</script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="colorMe">
<tr><td>2000</td><td>3500</td></tr>
<tr><td>3000</td><td>2500</td></tr>
<tr><td>4000</td><td>4500</td></tr>
</table>​
</body>
</html>

and here is the jquery code which is on a seperate page
// JavaScript Document
$("#d td").each(function rr() {
  var thisCell = $(this);
  var cellValue = parseInt(thisCell.text());

  if (!isNaN(cellValue) && (cellValue <=3000)) {
     thisCell.css("background-color","#FF0000");
  }
});
```

Comment: What exactly means "not working"? Do you get any error-messages? How is the javascript included? Do you have jquery included properly? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can't use both the `[src]` attribute and the contents of the `<script>` element, you'll need to use another `<script>` element.

Comment: The code is incomplete.  Your element with the id of 'd' is not even there in the markup.

Comment: Yeh just realised that but still it aint working. What I mean by not working is that when I load the html in the browser some cells should be red but they are not.

Comment: Here's a working fiddle of the colouring code you want, so if it doesn't work now then I suggest your problem is elsewhere... http://jsfiddle.net/3fPqx/

Comment: Also, check this out for awesome.... http://www.bennadel.com/blog/547-jQuery-Custom-Selectors-Holy-Cow-That-Is-So-Badass-.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery library to your code:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="yourcode.js type='text/javascript></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper usage would be:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="yourcode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       rr();
   });
</script>
</head>
```

and in the file `yourcode.js` you javascript code. Try this and then come back if you have further problems;)

<sup>Of course instead to the googleapis you could link directly to a local copy of jquery...</sup>

Comment: Are you using the right selector? According to your markup it should be `$(".colorMe td“)`.

Comment: @user1712552 This can't be - it is working fine [in this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HaUsw/). You must have your error elsewhere. Check your console for any errors please.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be selecting an ID (#d) in your javascript that doesn't exist in your HTML.  You also have not linked the jQuery library to your code.